# How to extract the numeric portion of a username

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract numbers from a user name that looks like this:

```
T12345maryjane
```

I have tried this expression, but doesn't seem to work:

```
^[^\d]+(\d+)([a-z,A-Z]+)$
```

Comment: Hello, please give more information to your problem, like what does not work? Also, you dont want to match the comma in the a-z brackets I assume, but apart from it the regex seems to be correct yielding two backreferences (the numbers and the name) So it might be something else..

Comment: [0-9]{1,} if i understood your question..

Comment: Please post the code. If `\d+`, or `[0-9]{1,}` or `[0-9]+` do not work, the reason is in the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the number of this specific user, then this will do:

```
/[0-9]+/
```

This will not work if you want both numbers in for example this username: R123Test34

I hope it helps!